# Exception PersistenceException overthrowing NoSuchException

Tags: java, exception

What is happening is that I have a Global class, and there I have some static final atributes, these atributes are defined by methods inside the Global class, I need the methods do get values from configuration files in my application directory.
I have a Sequence generator that uses one of the atributes from my global class, and because all of these atributes are static finals if any of them gets any error, my SequenceGenerator throws an Persistence Exception.
Here are some examples of what I have:

SequenceGenerator:

```
public static final String MUNICIPIO_PREFIX_DEFAULT = Global.siglaMun;
```

Global:

```
public static final String configDirectory = getDiretorioConfig();
public static final String municipio = getMunicipio();
public static final String siglaMun = getSiglaMun();
```

One of the methods that can fail:

```
public static String getMunicipio() throw new NoSuchElementException {
    try {
        String json = readConf("municipio.conf");
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        return jsonObject.get("municipio").toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Erro em arquivo de configuração.");
    }
}
```

Comment: **Always** chain your exceptions (i.e., `new NoSuchElementException("Erro em arquivo de configuração.", e)`) so that you see the underlying cause.

Comment: Well, I've searched chain exceptions and I understand why you thing this would help. But this doesn't help me, as I have no control of the "PersistenceException" that is being throwing, no matter how I throw the exception in the try/catch, the PersistenceException is being thrown because my Sequence Generator works like that.

Comment: Actually, the Persistence isn't thrown by the SequenceGenerator, it actually throws "MappingException"